# linking user accounts to their twitter/facebook/etc accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I have an existing rails app which uses 'devise' for authentication.

I would like user's to be able to link their twitter and facebook accounts to their account on my site, so that my application can post updates on their behalf.

Ideally:

- When registering, you can choose to set up a standard account, or use twitter, Facebook, etc credentials.
- If user chooses to use facebook credentials, I would still like them to be able to link their twitter account, so that my application can post to both at same time on their behalf.
- A bonus would be allowing them to have identities which they could link twitter account A to one identity, then switch identities and use another twitter acccount.

My questions are:

- if they use a standard account, and link facebook and twitter, are they going to be prompted to enter those credentials every time I post on their behalf? Or does omniauth give me an infinitely valid token?
- I know devise can handle omniauth, but I can't seem to tell if it can handle what I am asking. It seems that it's omniauth support is more along the lines of just authenticating site users against twitter credentials not for linking multiples.
- is there a rails gem that does this, and is well supported? I see socialite is no longer supported, but it seemed to be a one or the other type deal, not what I want anyway.
- because I am already doing standard auth with devise, would it be simpler to just force users to create a standard account, and then use the twitter and facebook api's directly on top of that?

Looking for the best strategy here for doing what I want.

*note: If you think I can get 75% of what I want for 25% of the effort that all my goals would be, let me know. *

Thanks,

~S

Comment: Most of these questions are answered by the omniauth docs. It's all easily done by the default behaviour, except the multiple twitter accounts part.

Comment: You should definitely watch these 2 Railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 & http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

Comment: Ok, off to watch the rails casts. I notice that there are updated versions of those rails casts. Anyone know how dated the free versions are?

Comment: I think someone awnser your question [check this out][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370461/connect-twitter-account-to-existing-devise-account