# uninitialized constant User::Authorization | omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I Followed the answer to my previous question -> [Connect Twitter Account to existing Devise Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370461/connect-twitter-account-to-existing-devise-account)

but getting a

```
NameError in Devise::Registrations#edit
uninitialized constant User::Authorization

app/models/user.rb:17:in `has_connection_with'
app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `check_connection'
app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:57:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb__1951492867192219113_70202479591960'
```

I'm trying to fix it, but nothing.. What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Authorization` model missing or relation between `Authorization` and `User` is missing.

`User` should have many `authorizations`, `authorization` belongs to `user`.