# Login Through Facebook (OmniAuth), and Increment User ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

I've successfully added facebook authentication via Oauth. I have a User model (I set up with devise) and I would like to redirect to the rails 'show' resource.  I would like to redirect to the new users profile page, so I added

```
      sign_in_and_redirect user_path, :event => :authentication
```

into the omniauth_callback_controller.

The problem with this is such:

the route for user_path is:

```
          user GET      /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
```

The :id here should increment each time a new user either registers through my site, or logs-in through facebook.  But Facebook doesn't know to pass a new ID to my DB, so can I inject an ID? All this information below COMES from facebook right? So the commented line I added couldn't do anything, and I don't think this would work because it would be facebook looking for current_user.. :(

```
   user = User.create( 
                ## id: current_user.id,
            name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                provider:auth.provider,
                uid:auth.uid,
                email:auth.info.email,
                password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          )
```

Help would be appreciated.  Thank you!  Let me know if I should post anything else.

Comment: @Abednego what's the point to increment the id of user in db? what are we talking about? id attribute is created by db and should not be changed in anyway, this is an unique id that is used to find record, if you change it you'll mess up all your records. What he needs is to send the id of user so he could use it in link to redirect to user page and there is no need to increment id in db for that.

Comment: I wasn't trying to change the unique ID, I was just trying to make sure it was added. I was confused and through all the params were coming from facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `sign_in_and_redirect user_path, :event => :authentication` means you should have a `current_user` available already, so you need to use it to pass the id:

```
sign_in_and_redirect user_path(current_user), :event => :authentication
```

or probably you'll need to use `resource` from devise, hard to say without seeing more of your controller code.

```
sign_in_and_redirect resource, :event => :authentication
```

**update - my example - using GPlus, LinkedIn, Facebook and Twitter** - see the line with `sign_in_and_redirect`

```
  def oauthorize(kind)
    @user = find_for_ouath(kind, env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user
      kind = 'Google+' if kind == 'GPlus'
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => kind
      session["devise.#{kind.downcase}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      # this is the line you need to look at
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  I tried user_path(current_user), but that doesn't work -> current_user is nil.

Comment: I don't really have a controller because I'm using devise.  Would I have to override devise controllers?

Comment: you might need to do that, not sure how you do authorizations with fb, the redirect should be exactly as I have it in answer. I'll update the answer with my example.

Comment: or update your question with the method where you are using `sign_in_and_redirect user_path, :event => :authentication `, also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370461/connect-twitter-account-to-existing-devise-account/21370950#21370950

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, it was way too late when I posted the question.  I was sloppy too and had a couple typos, but your contribution helped me see things better.  Thanks!